# JMenu : while trigger event from Jmenu for open dialoge (confirmbox) Joption yes/No option click twice to work

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I write code on JMenu(Exit) when click on it it open JOption Pane confirm message box  with yes/NO option but it not got focus first time when it popup yes/no button should be clicked twice to work .

After digging i realize the Jmenu (Exit )Option not lost focus when it generates popup after click once on any button it got focus next time trigger function so how I can Handle the situation .

```
JMenu menu5 = new JMenu("Exit");
        menu5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                requestFocus();
                callpopUp();
            }

            private void callpopUp() {
                int  choice=JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
                choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to Exit Application",
                       "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);


               if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("Exit Button Clicked.");
                   System.exit(0);
               }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The question really is, why are you using a `JMenu` for this purpose?

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Actually I have Menubar with menu Exit and Once I click on it . OptionPane with confirm box opened with YES/NO button.

Comment: Yes, but `JMenu` isn't suppose to work like this, it's meant to be a container for `JMenuItem`s, in which one should be your exit menu item. You approach is counter-intuitive and potentially confusing to the users

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Ok Got It I Modify the Scenario Accordingly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JMenu` isn't designed for this purpose, you should be using a `JMenuItem`

Start by having a look at [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Something like...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private JFrame frame;

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
                JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
                exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        performClose();
                    }
                });

                file.add(exit);
                mb.add(file);

                frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        performClose();
                    }

                });
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void performClose() {
        int choice = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
        choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to Exit Application",
                        "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Exit Button Clicked.");
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

This will allow you to use the `File->Exit` menu option or simply close the window through [X] button and it will perform the same operation, checking to see if the user wants to exit

Comment: The Action Listener Event Not Triggers With JMenu

Comment: @MohasinMujawar They do, that's how they are designed to work

Comment: If i Replace Mouse Listener with Action Listener then How i Can bind with Directly with JMenu not with any menu Item . i tried in above snippets replace code with Action Listener its not work for me

Comment: No sorry, you're talking about a `JMenu`, my bad, then the question really is, why are you using a `JMenu` for this purpose?

Comment: Ok Got It I Know The SubMenu/MenuItem way to do this but i just think it might be happen in this way also.